# Navigating in flask using JS

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to use JavaScript function to navigate to another flask route.

this is the function

```
dateClick: function(info) {
             alert('Date: ' + info.dateStr);
             alert('Resource ID: ' + info.resource.id);
          }
```

instead of alet I want it to navigate to this route

```
@app.route('/addPage')
def addPage():
    return render_template('manual_entry.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try looking at [windows.location.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign), it will change the tab URL to the one you give it.

If you wanted to without logging to the history of the current page (you can't use the back button then) then [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace).

Example of functions:

```js
// Variable function
let navigateTo = (url) => {
  window.location.assign(url);
}

// Or specific function
let navigateToStackoverflow = () => {
  window.location.assign("https://stackoverflow.com/");
}
```

Example of usage:

```html
<button role="button" onclick="navigateTo('https://my-url.org')">Click for Escape</button>

<button role="button" id="anotherEscapeBtn">Or maybe this way?</button>

<script type="application/javascript">
document.querySelector('body').onclick = navigateToStackoverflow;
</script>
```